# Get a Small Circle at Trim's Fill Value in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, geometry

I have a circle which I am **trimming** to my given **fill value**. I want to have another small circle at the end of that trim's fill value.

I have made a circle with fill value like this:

[image: my circle]

And my code for this is:

```
struct CountdownView: View {
  
  @State var fillValue: CGFloat = 0.7

  var body: some View {

      ZStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(radius: 0.5)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: fillValue)
                .stroke(Color.blue, style: .init(lineWidth: 6))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))

        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
        .padding()

  }
}
```

I want to have another small circle at the end of the **fillValue**. This is my required view:

[image: desired circle]

How can I add this small circle at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a small indicator circle which is offset to the right and then rotated so its centre is at the end of the stroke:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var fillValue: CGFloat = 0.7
    private let lineWidth = 6.0
    private let indicatorRadius = 6.0
    private let radius = 125.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(radius: 0.5)
                    
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: fillValue)
                .stroke(Color.blue, style: .init(lineWidth: lineWidth))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees( 
            
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: indicatorRadius * 2, height: indicatorRadius * 2)
                .offset(x: radius, y: 0)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90.0 + 360.0 * fillValue ))
        }
        .frame(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid math for a so simple "built-in" function. This should do the trick without using any external computation other than `.trim`

```swift
struct CountdownView: View {
    @State var fillValue: CGFloat = 0.7
    var lineWidth = 6.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Group {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(radius: 0.5)

                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: fillValue)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, style: .init(lineWidth: lineWidth))

                Circle() // 
                    .trim(from: fillValue, to: fillValue + 0.00002) // 
                    .stroke(Color.blue,
                            style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth * 2, lineCap: .round),
                            antialiased: true)
            }
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(90)) // 
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Result is as follow:
[image: Output image]